# Error in erasure phase when compiling Scala in IntelliJ 13

Tags: intellij-idea, scala-2.10, intellij-13

When I run the `sbt` task `compile` or `assembly` I don't see any compiler errors and I get a valid jar. When I run the run config from IntelliJ 13.1.1 #UI-135.480 I see the following error coming from scalac.

I tried running `sbt clean`, invalidating the cache, killing all nailgun runners, restarting IntelliJ IDEA. I always see this error now. I had a similar problem before and the only way to fix it was to delete every IntelliJ file from my computer and reinstall it. I'm hoping I don't have to do that this time. I am going to try this in IntelliJ 12 before I do.

Any ideas what this could be about?

> Error:scalac: Error: assertion failed: 
>        while compiling: /code/zensey/backend/common/CareDataExchange/src/test/scala/com/careverge/cigna/NotifierTest.scala
>           during phase: erasure
>        library version: version 2.10.3
>       compiler version: version 2.10.3   reconstructed args: -deprecation -language:experimental.macros -feature -classpath giant:ass:classpath
>   -unchecked -bootclasspath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/JObjC.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/classes:/Users/AudaxLoaner1/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.3/lib/scala-library.jar
>   last tree to typer: TypeTree(trait Seq)
>                 symbol: trait Seq in package collection (flags:  abstract  )    symbol definition:
>   abstract trait Seq[+A] extends PartialFunction[Int,A] with Iterable[A]
>   with GenSeq[A] with GenericTraversableTemplate[A,Seq] with
>   SeqLike[A,Seq[A]]
>                    tpe: Seq
>          symbol owners: trait Seq -> package collection
>         context owners: method convertToStringShouldWrapper -> class CareMailNotifierUtilTest -> package cigna
>   == Enclosing template or block == Apply( // override implicit def convertToStringShouldWrapper(o: String):
>   ShouldMatchers.this.StringShouldWrapper in trait ShouldMatchers,
>   tree.tpe=org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers#StringShouldWrapper
>   CareMailNotifierUtilTest.this."convertToStringShouldWrapper" //
>   override implicit def convertToStringShouldWrapper(o: String):
>   ShouldMatchers.this.StringShouldWrapper in trait ShouldMatchers,
>   tree.tpe=(o:
>   String)org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers#StringShouldWrapper   "o"
>   // o: String, tree.tpe=String )
>   == Expanded type of tree == TypeRef(   TypeSymbol(
>       abstract trait Seq[+A] extends PartialFunction[Int,A] with Iterable[A] with GenSeq[A] with GenericTraversableTemplate[A,Seq] with
>   SeqLike[A,Seq[A]]
>          )   normalize = PolyType(
>       typeParams = List(TypeParam(+A))
>       resultType = TypeRef(
>         TypeSymbol(
>           abstract trait Seq[+A] extends PartialFunction[Int,A] with Iterable[A] with GenSeq[A] with GenericTraversableTemplate[A,Seq] with
>   SeqLike[A,Seq[A]]
>
> ```
>   )
>   args = List(TypeParamTypeRef(TypeParam(+A)))
> )   ) ) class StringShouldWrapper java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: 
>  while compiling: /code/zensey/backend/common/CareDataExchange/src/test/scala/com/careverge/cigna/NotifierTest.scala
>     during phase: erasure
>  library version: version 2.10.3
> compiler version: version 2.10.3   reconstructed args: -deprecation -language:experimental.macros -feature -classpath giant:ass:classpath
> ```
>
> -unchecked -bootclasspath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/JObjC.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/classes:/Users/AudaxLoaner1/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.3/lib/scala-library.jar
>   last tree to typer: TypeTree(trait Seq)
>                 symbol: trait Seq in package collection (flags:  abstract  )    symbol definition:
>   abstract trait Seq[+A] extends PartialFunction[Int,A] with Iterable[A]
>   with GenSeq[A] with GenericTraversableTemplate[A,Seq] with
>   SeqLike[A,Seq[A]]
>                    tpe: Seq
>          symbol owners: trait Seq -> package collection
>         context owners: method convertToStringShouldWrapper -> class CareMailNotifierUtilTest -> package cigna
>   == Enclosing template or block == Apply( // override implicit def convertToStringShouldWrapper(o: String):
>   ShouldMatchers.this.StringShouldWrapper in trait ShouldMatchers,
>   tree.tpe=org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers#StringShouldWrapper
>   CareMailNotifierUtilTest.this."convertToStringShouldWrapper" //
>   override implicit def convertToStringShouldWrapper(o: String):
>   ShouldMatchers.this.StringShouldWrapper in trait ShouldMatchers,
>   tree.tpe=(o:
>   String)org.scalatest.matchers.ShouldMatchers#StringShouldWrapper   "o"
>   // o: String, tree.tpe=String )
>   == Expanded type of tree == TypeRef(   TypeSymbol(
>       abstract trait Seq[+A] extends PartialFunction[Int,A] with Iterable[A] with GenSeq[A] with GenericTraversableTemplate[A,Seq] with
>   SeqLike[A,Seq[A]]
>          )   normalize = PolyType(
>       typeParams = List(TypeParam(+A))
>       resultType = TypeRef(
>         TypeSymbol(
>           abstract trait Seq[+A] extends PartialFunction[Int,A] with Iterable[A] with GenSeq[A] with GenericTraversableTemplate[A,Seq] with
>   SeqLike[A,Seq[A]]
>
> ```
>   )
>   args = List(TypeParamTypeRef(TypeParam(+A)))
> )   ) ) class StringShouldWrapper     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.AddInterfaces.transformMixinInfo(AddInterfaces.scala:213)
> ```
>
> at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure.transformInfo(Erasure.scala:329)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.transform.InfoTransform$Phase$$anon$1.transform(InfoTransform.scala:38)
>     at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.rawInfo(Symbols.scala:1312)
>     at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$Symbol.info(Symbols.scala:1239)   at
>   scala.reflect.internal.Types$ClassTypeRef$class.baseType(Types.scala:2186)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.Types$TypeRef$$anon$6.baseType(Types.scala:2544)
>     at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.firstTry$1(Types.scala:6058)
>     at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.isSubType2(Types.scala:6222)
>     at scala.reflect.internal.Types$class.isSubType(Types.scala:5831)   at
>   scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.isSubType(SymbolTable.scala:13)    at
>   scala.reflect.internal.Types$Type.$less$colon$less(Types.scala:872)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.scala$tools$nsc$transform$Erasure$Eraser$$adaptToType(Erasure.scala:690)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.adapt(Erasure.scala:816)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5626)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.transformedOrTyped(Typers.scala:5811)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedDefDef(Typers.scala:2256)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5535)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:835)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5608)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedStat$1(Typers.scala:2927)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$60.apply(Typers.scala:3031)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$60.apply(Typers.scala:3031)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:170)   at
>   scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:186)   at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3031)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedTemplate(Typers.scala:1918)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedClassDef(Typers.scala:1758)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5549)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:835)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5608)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.scala$tools$nsc$typechecker$Typers$Typer$$typedStat$1(Typers.scala:2927)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$60.apply(Typers.scala:3031)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer$$anonfun$60.apply(Typers.scala:3031)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:170)   at
>   scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:186)   at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedStats(Typers.scala:3031)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typedPackageDef$1(Typers.scala:5267)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed1(Typers.scala:5553)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$Eraser.typed1(Erasure.scala:835)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5608)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.typed(Typers.scala:5670)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer$$anonfun$transform$2.apply(Erasure.scala:1291)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer$$anonfun$transform$2.apply(Erasure.scala:1287)
>     at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.atPhase(SymbolTable.scala:207)
>     at
>   scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.afterPhase(SymbolTable.scala:216)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer.transform(Erasure.scala:1287)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.transform.Erasure$ErasureTransformer.transform(Erasure.scala:888)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.ast.Trees$Transformer.transformUnit(Trees.scala:227)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.transform.Transform$Phase.apply(Transform.scala:30)
>     at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:464)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Global.scala:431)
>     at
>   scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Global.scala:431)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)  at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)    at
>   scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.run(Global.scala:431)  at
>   scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1583)    at
>   scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1557)    at
>   scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1553)  at
>   scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1662)     at
>   xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:126)     at
>   xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:102)     at
>   xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:27)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:102)  at
>   sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:48)    at
>   sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:41)    at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.IdeaIncrementalCompiler.compile(IdeaIncrementalCompiler.scala:28)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.local.LocalServer.compile(LocalServer.scala:25)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.make(Main.scala:58)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main$.nailMain(Main.scala:21)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.scala.remote.Main.nailMain(Main.scala)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)     at
>   com.martiansoftware.nailgun.NGSession.run(NGSession.java:319)

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I'm hitting a similar problem as well.

Comment: Nope. I just killed IntelliJ with fire and deleted everything.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that helped me was deleting all the "target" directories in the project and running `compile` again (Steps that didn't help include invalidating caches, reloading project and running `clean`).